# Payment verification with the iOS Paypal SDK - Clarification needed please

Tags: ios, paypal

I have a specific question about the verification side of Paypal (using the latest iOS PayPal SDK)

From this document: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

This is mentioned:

> Send the payment response to your servers for verification, as well as any other processing required for your business, such as fulfillment. Tip: At this point, the payment has been completed, and the user has been charged. If you can't reach your server, it is important that you save the proof of payment and try again later.

And from there is a link to the verify-mobile payments documentation, in which various things are mentioned, i'm assuming this part applies to the iOS SDK (latest)

> Looking up a payment using the REST API
>   You can payment id value in a response to look up a payment by calling the REST API. The following example retrieves a payment in the sandbox:
>
> curl
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI
>   \  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \  -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   {accessToken}" You should verify that the Payment:
>
> Is approved ("state": "approved"). Contains a Transaction with: An
>   Amount with total and currency that match your expectation. A Sale
>   that is completed (in related_resources, with "state": "completed").
>   The live endpoint is
>   https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/{payment_id}.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Got it. So given the above assumptions (which I hope are correct!) what should one do with the details returned from the server? Save them to a database?

The docs seem to be a little vague in terms of this particular subject. This is my understanding of the flow:

1) Make payment.

2) Send payment details to server.

3) Get back payment state from server.

4) Check that it's approved and the other details match up (amount, currency etc)

5) Upon making another payment, check to see if the payment id has already been used? This is another part of my confusion.

Thank you in advance for any assistance. Just would like some clarification in layman's terms to see if I understand the flow correctly.

Answer (score 0):

from the sdk you will get a response which will have a `state` and `id`. the `id` you should save to database for your purposes, because you can always call `/payments/id` https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource and see the details of it. Every `id` is unique. `state` will have more information if the payment has been successful or not. Please check documentation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have checked and read the documentation, but it isn't very clear on the steps I have outlined above (in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks! i will pass your feedback to relevant team.